# printing and formatted list in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am currently using the following code

```
print "line 1     line2"
for h, m in zip(human_score, machine_score):
    print "{:5.1f}      {:5.3f}".format(h,m)
```

But it might not be good practice to just use spaces between "line 1" and "line 2" in the header. And I'm not sure how to add a variable amount of spaces before each row so that I can fit "mean" and "std" at the bottom, and have those two numbers in line with the list above it.

For example, I would like it printed like this:

```
       Line 1      Line 2
         -6.0      7.200
         -5.0      6.377
        -10.0      14.688
         -5.0      2.580
         -8.0      8.421
         -3.0      2.876
         -6.0      9.812
         -8.0      6.218
         -8.0      15.873
          7.5      -2.805
Mean:  -0.026      7.26 
Std:    2.918      6.3
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use larger field sizes, e.g., for your header use:

```
print "{:>17} {:>17s}".format('line1', 'line2')
```

and for your numbers:

```
print "{:>17.1f}      {:>12.3f}".format(h,m)
```

your footer:

```
print 
print "Mean: {:11.2f}      {:12.3f}".format(-0.026, 7.26)
print "Std : {:11.2f}      {:12.3f}".format(2.918, 6.3)
```

which would give you

```
            line1             line2
             -6.0             7.200
             -5.0             6.377
            -10.0            14.688
             -5.0             2.580
             -8.0             8.421
             -3.0             2.876
             -6.0             9.812
             -8.0             6.218
             -8.0            15.873
              7.5            -2.805

Mean:       -0.03             7.260
Std :        2.92             6.300
```

You can adjust the field width values according to your needs.

Comment: @Zach You are welcome. `.format()` is quite powerful, worth getting to know better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same printing technique for headers as you do for data, treating the header words as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question was about how to avoid putting arbitrary spaces between the fields in the format string. You are right to try to avoid this. Even more flexibility comes with not hard-coding the padding width for the columns.

You can do both by using a WIDTH 'constant' defined outside the format string. The width then gets passed into the format function as a parameter, and inserted into the format string in another set of braces, inside the replacement field: `{foo:>{width}}`:

If you want to change the column width, just change the 'constant' `WIDTH`:

```
human_score = [1.23, 2.32,3.43,4.24]
machine_score = [0.23, 4.22,3.33,5.21]
WIDTH = 12
mean = "Mean:"
std = "Std:"
print '{0:>{width}}{1:>{width}}'.format('line 1', 'line 2', width=WIDTH)
for h, m in zip(human_score, machine_score):
    print "{:>{width}.1f}{:>{width}.3f}".format(h,m, width=WIDTH)

print "{mean}{:>{width1}.2f}{:>{width2}.3f}".format(-0.026, 7.26, width1=WIDTH-len(mean), width2=WIDTH, mean=mean)
print "{std}{:>{width1}.2f}{:>{width2}.3f}".format(-2.918, 6.3, width1=WIDTH-len(std), width2=WIDTH, std=std)
```

Outputs:

```
      line 1      line 2
         1.2       0.230
         2.3       4.220
         3.4       3.330
         4.2       5.210
Mean:  -0.03       7.260
Std:   -2.92       6.300
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ljust` or `rjust`

Some examples [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use str.rjust and str.ljust and relate this with the digits in the score.